# PayPal search option is not displaying in admin section OpenCart

Tags: php, search, paypal, opencart2.3

I have follow OpenCart documentation for paypal settings in OpenCart version **2.3.0.2** http://docs.opencart.com/sale/paypal/

The PayPal Search section in admin panel allows us to search for all the transactions made to our PayPal account. The section can be accessed under `Sales > PayPal > Search.`

But it's not displaying, I have installed the paypal expess checkout module, added the credentials and enabled it.

What could be the reasons for this? Is there any other settings needed to make it visible paypal sales search display in admin section?

Answer (score 0):

In the mentioned url there is a note:
**Note. For the PayPal Search section to work, you need to setup your PayPal Express Checkout account.**
I search for that also!